# Sonarqube: spark is not defined. Change its name or define it before using it

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, sonarqube, databricks

We run our code on Databricks where SparkSession and SparkContext are defined in the backend of the platform. However, when our code is analysed by Sonarqube, we keep having these false positive bugs. Then we need to manually flag as a false positive. How can that be overcome? Not sure if in Sonarqube side or in the code itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In PySpark there is a method you can use to either get the current session by name if it already exists or create a new one if it does not exist. In your scenario it sounds like Databricks has the session already created (so the get or create would just get the session) and in sonarqube it sounds like the session is not created yet so this method would create it for you and should alleviate the error.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('YourAppName').getOrCreate()
```